# Access .NET properties from SilkTest classic

Tags: .net, silktest

Is it possible to access .NET properties using SilkTest classic (4Test language)?
I need to read value of labels that are shown on `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` control.

I can't use `GetProperty` or `DynamicInvoke` because when they return something, 4Test automatically converts it to string. So if I call `GetProperty("Legends")`, I'll get just `Legends.ToString()`, not the actual `LegendCollection` object.

Comment: You know you can cascade multiple invoke calls, right? So if you want a single `Legend`, you could `.Get` it from the `LegendCollection`. The `Legend`-object then again would be `.ToString`ed, but you could also call another method/property if that would make more sense.

Comment: @tehlexx: I didn't know that I could do that. Can you please provide me with an example?

Comment: This article (http://community.microfocus.com/borland/test/silk_test/w/wiki/809.testing-custom-controls-with-silk-test.aspx) covers using dynamic invoke as well as cascading invokes to handle custom types like in your case.

Comment: @tehlexx: Thanks! I've already found the article and solved my problem. Would you like to post this as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this article](http://community.microfocus.com/borland/test/silk_test/w/wiki/809.testing-custom-controls-with-silk-test.aspx) you can use cascading `dynamicInvoke`-calls to access the elements in the `LegendCollection`.

You can then also access properties of that element if the default `ToString()` is not appropriate for you.